# Evaluate the limit of integral

Tags: calculus

Task from school entrance examinations of past years. I tryed to use L'Hopital's rule but there is $\frac{1}{t+x}$ in integrable function and that's the problem... Are there other solutions?

$ \lim_{x \to 0} \int_{0}^{x} \frac{cos(t^3)}{(t+x)}dt $

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Someone voted for close. I think it is a more or less ok question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $t=xs$, so
$$
\int_0^x\frac{\cos(t^3)}{t+x}dt = \int_0^1\frac{\cos(x^3s^3)}{xs+x}xds
=\int_0^1\frac{\cos(x^3s^3)}{s+1}ds,
$$
therefore
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\int_0^x\frac{\cos(t^3)}{t+x}dt &= 
\lim_{x\to 0}\int_0^1\frac{\cos(x^3s^3)}{s+1}ds  \\
&=\int_0^1\frac{1}{s+1}ds  \\
&=\ln(s+1)\bigg|_0^1=\ln 2.
\end{align}

Comment: but why t=xs ? x and t are independent varibles

Comment: Oh, thank you so much!

Comment: Nice answer +1.
@Angedon this change of variable trick is often used when we have integrals " going from 0 to *0* "